# Installing a python package on some other machine through setup.py

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to deploy my package on some server, for that i came across with the concept of setup.py, so thought of trying a simple poc.I downloaded a package called vision from git and want to upload it on some other machine,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import io
import re
import shutil
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def read(*names, **kwargs):
    with io.open(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *names),
        encoding=kwargs.get("encoding", "utf8")
    ) as fp:
        return fp.read()


def find_version(*file_paths):
    version_file = read(*file_paths)
    version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]",
                              version_file, re.M)
    if version_match:
        return version_match.group(1)
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")


readme = open('README.rst').read()

VERSION = find_version('torchvision', '__init__.py')

requirements = [
    'numpy',
    'pillow >= 4.1.1',
    'six',
    'torch',
]

setup(
    # Metadata
    name='torchvision',
    version=VERSION,
    author='',
    author_email='',
    url='10.205.1.73',
    description='image and video datasets and models for torch deep learning',
    long_description=readme,
    license='BSD',

    # Package info
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('test',)),

    zip_safe=True,

)
```

This is the code that am trying, am new to this so dont know the process involved. I had gon ethrough the tutorials  and examples but they all point to pypi site.

Comment: What is exactly your question? I wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

> For extreme simplicity you can always use the `subprocess` module.

Using the `subprocess.call()` you can call terminal commands easily:
(Given those commands don't require superuser level privilege)

```
import subprocess as sub
sub.call(['apt-get install','something'],shell=True) 
#Here i am using aptik but you can use whatever you want eg. pip
```

**Note**: Keep in my that form your case you've got to execute the setup.py as **root** to achieve success by this method.
So, running it like below will do:

`$sudo python setup.py`

Comment: but what does the url in setup( ) do

Comment: does it hold the destination address

Comment: The module `setuptools` is for releasing your library or module in pypi, I don't think that's what you really need,  you just need to install dependencies so that your package can run smoothly on the server, right??So just for installing dependencies, you can inculde the above-answered code to make it happen without using `setuptools` . Anyway for more information on `setuptools` read [this.](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)